# JQuery Mobile swipe events not working on mobile website

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, web

I am at a loss right now. I recently had to upgrade a web application from JQM 1.3 to 1.4 to get rid of a pretty serious bug, but now there's a new bug. Our app contains a number of pages that are supposed to be flipped via $(element).on ('swiperight', function), but the swipe event doesn't get received by the function (I put a breakpoint in the function body, and when I swipe it doesn't pause). This only happens on touch devices. If I click and drag on a desktop/laptop, the swipe gets handled.

This only seems to happen on my website. I've demoed this functionality in another application, and it works fine on touch screens. I'm using the latest jquery as well. Does anybody have any idea why this would be happening?

Comment: Maybe some other jquery plugin that interfere ? Do you use the same versions of jquery and jquery mobile on the other application where the functionality does work ?

Comment: I just went in and loaded all of the same scripts and stylesheets into my working demo as are in the app. Swiping still works in the demo.

Comment: Well remove as much code as possible in the "broken" demo, and provide the code. Can't help otherwise.